# How to do centroid clustering of sequences?

Tags: r, traminer, sequence-analysis, euclidean

I want to cluster sequences using centroids. In the `hclust` package it is noted that *"Method "centroid" is typically meant to be used with squared Euclidean distances"*.

Further, it seems as if `TraMineRextras` allows for conversion of state sequence objects to euclidean distances using `seqemlt()`. However, these do not seem to be squared. So, to get `hclust` to work with centroids, do I simply square the output of `seqemlt()` like so:

```
euclidean.distances^2
```

...and then put this object through `hclust()`?

Comment: It is true that centroid hierarchical method, in order to compute euclidean distance between centroids must operate on _squared_ pairwise distances between the objects. I'm not `R` user but I suppose that you are right. Square the distances and input the matrix to `hclust`.

Answer (score 3):

The `seqemlt` function from the `TraMineRextras` package does not return a dissimilarity matrix, but a numerical representation (matrix `coord`) of the sequences such that the Euclidean distances between the numerical transformed representations (rows of `coord`) correspond to the distances between sequences proposed by [Rousset, Giret & Grelet al. (2012)](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00703624). If you compute the Euclidean distances between the rows of `coord` with `dist`, the results are non squared distances.

However, Rousset et al's distance is a very specific distance (see [Studer & Ritschard, 2014](http://www.lives-nccr.ch/sites/default/files/pdf/publication/33_lives_wp_studer_sequencedissmeasures.pdf), p. 9) and you should not use it without having an idea of what you are measuring.

There are alternative ways of getting Euclidean distances. Using any dissimilarity measure ---such as optimal matching for example---you get numerical representations of the sequences by means of multidimensional scaling (e.g., see the R `cmdscale` function). You can then simply use the Euclidean distances between those numerical representations, which you obtain for instance with `dist`.

Hope this helps.