# TraMineR: predicting class membership of new sequences

Tags: clustering, sequence-analysis, traminer

#### Question summary

This question pertains to analyzing dissimilarities between discrete state sequences (e.g., using `TraMineR`), more specifically to classifying new, previously unseen sequences based on the cluster solution from earlier analytical steps.

#### What we have

The analytical situation at hand is as follows:

1. We have a number of sequences (e.g., life course) with a defined alphabet. For example, family situation at year 1, year 2, and so forth.
2. We have computed a dissimilarity matrix $D$ between our sequences, e.g., using Optimal Matching (OM).
3. We have clustered the sequences at hand into $K$ clusters, e.g., using Partitioning Around Medoids (PAM).

#### What we want to have

Suppose we have a new, previously unseen sequence $s$, and we want to assign it to one of the $K$ clusters. The most straightforward strategy would probably be to re-run the entire cluster analysis and examine to which cluster $s$ belongs and whether it influenced the clustering solution. A problem with this approach is that the entire dissimilarity matrix $D'$ and the entire clustering solution need to be constructed from scratch, and for larger samples (e.g., $N > 30000$) this is computationally unfeasible.

#### Possible avenues

From a cursory review of available information in this respect, it seems that there are `K-means` family algorithms that can assign new observations to classes. However, these seem to work with raw data to obtain distances, and not with distance/dissimilarity matrices that OM produces. [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130357/how-to-do-centroid-clustering-of-sequences) offers a workaround to obtain Euclidean distances from the dissimilarity matrix $D$. I'm not sure whether this is a robust method, though, and would love to hear some comments on it.

Another, perhaps very primitive approach would be to calculate OM distances between $s$ and $K$ medoid sequences from the initial solution, and pick the shortest one. Again, I feel that there might be complexities there, that this approach cannot account for (aside the fact that $s$ itself may change the structure of the solution).

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alongside the solutions you are suggesting, you can also determine the membership of a new sequence on the basis of the mean distance to group members. This is easily done with `TraMineR` if you use one of the metric that supports the `refseq` argument. This is the case of OM. I illustrate using the `actcal` data:

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal)
lab <- c("Full-time", "Part-time", "Short Part-time", "Unemployed")
## sequences of first 1000 sequences
s <- seqdef(actcal[1:1000,13:24],labels = lab)

## OM distances using data-driven costs based on "INDELSLOG"
cost <- seqcost(s, method="INDELSLOG")
diss <- seqdist(s, method="OM", indel = cost$indel, sm = cost$sm)

## 4 cluster solution based on PAM
library(WeightedCluster)
pam4 <- wcKMedoids(diss, k=4)
summary(cl <- factor(pam4$clustering))
# group labels correspond to indexes of the medoids
## 979  994  996 1000 
##  90  166  418  326 

## compute dissimlarities of sequence 1001 to the first 1000.
s.1001 <- seqdef(actcal[1001,13:24],alphabet=alphabet(s),labels = lab)
diss.1001 <- seqdist(s, method="OM", indel = cost$indel, sm = cost$sm, refseq=s.1001)

(mean.d <- aggregate(diss.1001, by=list(cl), FUN = mean))

##   Group.1         x
## 1     979 11.252927
## 2     994  8.824404
## 3     996  1.855171
## 4    1000  9.389470
```

The membership would then be

```
mean.d$Group.1[mean.d$x == min(mean.d$x)]
```

which returns "996". Medoid of group 996 is

```
s[996,]
## 847  A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
```

and supplementary sequence is

```
s.1001
## 3399 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-B-B
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm getting an error (`'refseq' must be less than the number of sequences in 'seqdata'`), since there are only 1000 sequences in `s`, and `refseq = 1001` points to NULL. The idea is clear, nevertheless, and the error can probably be solved by defining another sequence set `s.1001`, and then eliminate the last element of `diss.1001` (equal to zero) to keep it conform to the size of `cl`. Alternatively, perhaps, supply a sequence object to `refseq`. Thanks again!

Comment: Of course, you are right. Thanks. I have fixed the code.